# Is mono-devel needed?

Tags: cinnamon, mono

**Ubuntu 18.04, Cinnamon.**

Recently installed Pinta and it has that issue where it just crashes and closes. It's no longer supported unfortunately so searched and came up with a supposed fix. It was mentioned that the fix only worked for 'some' installations. I did not work for mine.

Main part of the fix was to install "mono-devel". That seemed to take quite a while and while I didn't read every installed line as it passed by in Term, seems to have used a bunch of disk space too.

Mono is well over a decade old, but if I do a google search I can't find much information on what it's for. I'm not much interested in cross platforming with Windows since I can just use a VM so I probably won't need it so I was thinking I'll just remove it.

My question is, is there *any reason* to leave it on the HDD? I do have plenty of HDD space I just don't care for a cluttered drive with unused software just lying around doing nothing.

Should I remove it, or does it do something or support something that's important that I haven't installed yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Results of `apt-cache rdepends mono-devel`:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends mono-devel
mono-devel
Reverse Depends:
  mono-mcs
  monodevelop
  nant
  mono-xsp4-base
  fsharp
  mono-complete
  libmono-cil-dev
 |cli-common-dev
```

As you can see, although mono-runtime is a dependency of pinta mono-devel is not, so you can safely uninstall mono-devel without it affecting pinta. There isn't any reason to leave mono-devel on your HDD unless you have any of the programs in the block quoted list in the answer installed.

Comment: OK, but my question was, "Is there any reason to leave it on my HDD?"

Comment: @user464356 There isn't any reason to leave mono-devel on your HDD unless you have any of the programs in the block quoted list in the answer installed.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Didn't recognize any of those listed as programs. Thanks.